# Xunit - Moq - Autofixture changes.. are the removed features coming back?

Tags: moq, xunit, autofixture

It seems that Xunit no longer supports extending TraitAttributes. They have sealed the class.

There are also some other issues with Autofixture's plugin for AutoData() where we can inject random created data through an attribute. There are a few work around's for this, however I am attempting to evaluate this for a larger product overall.  I liked the demo's since they could do small things like SQL, Excel, custom Attributes for category.

It seems there was more functionality before the changes. I have looked at the site and still see some of the features are returning and there isn't much information.

Is there a new set of functionality coming out?  Or possibly a change that will allow us to recreate the older functionality in a new way?  It seems the SQL and Excel have a work around, however I can't find any information about when the latest version will be compatible with "Autofixture with xUnit.net data theories" Nuget package.   I really like what I have seen, though I can say I don't like breaking changes when I look at enterprise solutions. I cringe a little when I think about if I had this in place in an enterprise and I had made a lot of custom attributes, or used Moq and Autofixture to populate and now all my tests were broken. So I guess the other question is, does Xunit seem to change a lot with breaking changes?  There is the other option of moving Xunit back a version. Though at some point I would need to know if these things would be fixed or if they were permanently removed, since I wouldn't want to spend time using functionality that is being removed.

Another is AutoFixtureMoqAutoDataAttribute that doesn't load without that side Nuget package.  With the side nuget packages not being updated.

I guess the end question may be.. Does anyone know of any plans to get these features to work with the current version of xunit so that I can start implementing and then expect to do mass replaces later?  Or are these permanently breaking changes where we shouldn't implement anything that is currently missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

If you want to use xUnit.net **1.x** with AutoFixture, use [AutoFixture.Xunit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit).

If you want to use xUnit.net **2.x** with AutoFixture, use [AutoFixture.Xunit2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2).

**Explanation**

xUnit.net 2.0 introduced **breaking changes**, compared to xUnit.net 1.x (e.g. 1.9.2). For AutoFixture, we wanted to make sure that AutoFixture supports both. There are people who want to upgrade to xUnit.net 2.x as soon as possible, but there are also people who, for various reasons, will need to stay with xUnit.net 1.x for a while longer.

For the people who wanted or needed to stay with xUnit.net 1.x for the time being, we wanted to make sure that they'd still get all the benefits of various bug fixes and new features for the AutoFixture core, so we're maintaining two parallel (but feature complete) Glue Libraries for AutoFixture and xUnit.net.

As an example, we've just released [AutoFixture 3.30.3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture/3.30.3), which addresses a defect in AutoFixture itself. This bug fix thus becomes available for both xUnit.net 1.x and 2.x users.

Thus, when you need to migrate from xUnit.net 1.x to xUnit.net 2.x, you should uninstall AutoFixture.Xunit and instead install AutoFixture.Xunit2. As far as I know, there should be feature parity between the two.

**Traits**

AutoFixture.Xunit and AutoFixture.Xunit2 don't use the `[Trait]` attribute, so I don't know exactly what you have in mind regarding this.

**AutoMoq**

Again, when it comes to [AutoFixture.AutoMoq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq/), it doesn't depend on xUnit.net, so I don't understand the question here as well. It sounds like a separate concern, so you may want to consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, understood. My issues are mainly on the combination of data theories in autofixture with data theories package.  There were a combination of questions from Moq/Xunit/Autofixture where they are all needed to get to these issues.  Autodata is xunit-autofixture.  I'd mark you up, but new rules don't allow for it :/

Comment: Xunit2 worked like a charm, thank you.  Was just reading your blog on http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/WhyImmigratingfromMSTesttoxUnit.net/